# How to check if there's an element inside another element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The main idea is: I have a list of `beverage` in a `div` and I'd like to `check` if the beverages are `out of stock or not`, and `click` the `first drink available` in stock. It needs to be in **JavaScript (without JQuery)**

The elements are in this `hierarchy`:

`Main div` containing all the drinks: `class="ob-menu-items__items"`

`Each drink` will be in a `H4` `class="ob-menu-item__title"`

If the product is `out of stock` there will be a `span` `class="ob-menu-item__out-of-stock"` with the `text " - Out of Stock"`

So far I try this (and got stuck):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    // iterating over each drink.
    var drink = document.getElementsByClassName("ob-menu-item__title")[i];
    if (document.getElementsByClassName(".ob-menu-item__out-of-stock").parents(drink).length == 1) {
        // There's out of stock text
        // Do nothing and go to the next drink 
    } else {
        //The product is available. Clik the drink and exit the loop
        document.getElementsByClassName("ob-menu-item__title")[i].click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] or your issue, instead of vague verbal paraphrasing like _“The elements are in this hierarchy […]”_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `if` condition as below and it will work as expected. It will find `elements` inside `drinks` which has class `ob-menu-item__out-of-stock`.

```
if (drink.getElementsByClassName("ob-menu-item__out-of-stock").length > 0)
```

---

Please refer [this answer which says `.getElementsByClassName("home")[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54952474/9695286) should not be used. You can alternatively use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like below. Replace `getElementsByClassName` with `querySelectorAll` and pass `class name` with `class selector (.)`. So `document.getElementsByClassName("ob-menu-item__title")[i]` will be replaced with `document.querySelectorAll(".ob-menu-item__title")[i]`.

To find `elements` inside `selected` element you can use `element.querySelectorAll` which is done inside `if` with `drink.querySelectorAll(".ob-menu-item__out-of-stock").length`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    // iterating over each drink.
    var drink = document.querySelectorAll(".ob-menu-item__title")[i];
    if (drink.querySelectorAll(".ob-menu-item__out-of-stock").length > 0) {
        // There's out of stock text
        // Do nothing and go to the next drink 
    } else {
        //The product is available. Clik the drink and exit the loop
        drink.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Try it below.

```js
// get all drink
var drinks = document.querySelectorAll(".ob-menu-item__title");
// iterating over each drink.
for (var i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
  let drink = drinks[i];

  if (drink.querySelectorAll(".ob-menu-item__out-of-stock").length > 0) {
  console.log('out of stock. i = ' + i);
    // There's out of stock text
    // Do nothing and go to the next drink 
  } else {
    //The product is available. Clik the drink and exit the loop
    console.log('In stock. i = ' + i);
    drink.click();
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='ob-menu-items__items'>
  <h4 class='ob-menu-item__title'>
    item0<span class='ob-menu-item__out-of-stock'> - Out of stock</span>
  </h4>
  <h4 class='ob-menu-item__title'>
    item4<span class='ob-menu-item__out-of-stock'> - Out of stock</span>
  </h4>
  <h4 class='ob-menu-item__title'>
    item2<span class='ob-menu-item__out-of-stock'> - Out of stock</span>
  </h4>
  <h4 class='ob-menu-item__title'>
    item3
  </h4>
  <h4 class='ob-menu-item__title'>
    item4
  </h4>
  <h4 class='ob-menu-item__title'>
    item5
  </h4>
  <h4 class='ob-menu-item__title'>
    item6
  </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `childElementCount` to find how many items there are. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_childelementcount.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var drink = document.getElementsByClassName("ob-menu-item__title")[i];
    if (document.getElementsByClassName.("ob-menu-item__out-of-stock").parents(drink).length == 1) {
        // There's out of stock text
        // Do nothing and go to the next drink 
    } else {
        //The product is available. Clik the drink and exit the loop
        document.getElementsByClassName("ob-menu-item__title")[i].click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

The hard-coded `7` in the for loop initialization doesn't look good. You can just find all the drinks by `document.querySelectorAll` and then find the one to click by checking for the span in each of them.

ES6 one-liner:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.ob-menu-item__title')]
  .find( drink => !drink.querySelector('.ob-menu-item__out-of-stock') )
  .click()
```

What it does is: converts the `querySelectorAll` result into an Array, then uses [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method which returns the first element that satisfied the callback, and the call back in this case returns `true` if given element doesn't contain the "out of stock" span.

More "classic" JS:

```
var firstInStock = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ob-menu-item__title'))
  .find( function(drink){
    if( drink.querySelector('.ob-menu-item__out-of-stock') ){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
firstInStock.click()
```

Or if you really want a for loop:

```
var drinks = document.querySelectorAll('.ob-menu-item__title');
for(var i=0; i< drinks.length; i++){
   if( !drink.querySelector('.ob-menu-item__out-of-stock') ){
     drink.click();
     break;
   }
}
```